# Hash with array of characters as key

Tags: ruby

I need to have a Hash in which keys are represented by arrays with chars.
But when i have arrays like these:

```
a = %w(a b c), b = %w(d e f), c = %w(g h i)
```

and i create a new Hash and try to give it values, my results are strange, i expect something similar to this:

```
H = { ["a", "b", "c"] => 1, ["d", "e", "f"] => 2 }
```

but i get something like this:

```
{"[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"=>1}
```

The way i create this hash is simple:

```
H = {}
H["#{array_name}"]
```

Is this normal behaviour? If so how can i make these keys normal arrays of chars?

Comment: `"#{variable}"` is string interpolation. So you're converting your array to it's string representation. and setting that string as a key.

Comment: Kuba, you should review Ruby's [naming convention](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html).  Variables are written with lowercase letters.  You might use `h = ` or `my_hash = ` rather than `H = `.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree with you..

Comment: i know those conventions, just wanted this post to be more readable:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a`,`b`,`c` are local variables. They are not array names. They are holding the references of 3 different `Array` instances. So do as below :

```
a = %w(a b c)
b = %w(d e f)
c = %w(g h i)
H = {}
H[a] = 1
H[b] = 2
H[c] = 3
H # => {["a", "b", "c"]=>1, ["d", "e", "f"]=>2, ["g", "h", "i"]=>3}
```

One Rubyish way :

```
a = %w(a b c), %w(d e f), %w(g h i)
Hash[a.zip([1,2,3])]
# => {["a", "b", "c"]=>1, ["d", "e", "f"]=>2, ["g", "h", "i"]=>3}
```

Comment: great, i thought you have to define hash keys with ""

Comment: Or the new to_h: `a.zip([1,2,3]).to_h`.

Comment: @steenslag Is it 2.1 features...?